# Wordpress: Rename "My Account" to member's name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to rename "My Account" to members' name exp: "John" (refer the image below):

[image]

I've tried change in wp-content/themes/themeName/framework/functions/woo-account.php:

```
printf( __( '%s', 'wpdance' ),$current_user->user_lastname);
```

previously:

```
printf( __( 'My Account', 'wpdance' ));
```

But still not working.

Thank you.

Comment: SO is not a place to ask for plugins. If you want to implement this yourself, go look at what actions/filters may be available to hook into to achieve this; if you want to find a plugin, you'll have to go research that yourself.

Comment: @CBroe thank you for your advice. Due to answer by ElvinHaci is helpful, I might remain this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply go to  YOUR_URL/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page and you will see that "My Account" page there (it is automatically created by WooCommerce). Rename that page, and that's all.

To show the name of current user instead of "My account", add this code to your functions.php file.

```
function rename_my_account( $title, $id = null ) {
    if ( $title=='My account' and is_user_logged_in()) {
        $current_user=wp_get_current_user();
        return $current_user->display_name;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'rename_my_account', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: @ElvinHaci how can we use your code without changing the breadcrumb navigation? The code still works with WooCommerce 3.5.1, but it changes the breadcrumb navigation as well. Huge thanks in advance.

Comment: @WooDevil, try this: add this code above  "return $current_user->display_name;" line.  if (!empty($GLOBALS["already_changed_title"])) { return $title; } else {$GLOBALS["already_changed_title"]=1;}

Comment: @ElvinHaci no, that did unfortunately not work. Adding that changes it back to the way it was = "My account".

Comment: can you show me the final state of your code. i guess you placed the change to the wrong place